# WPF Prism/Unity Loading an External UserControl

Tags: wpf, unity-container, prism

My app is setup like the following:

Shell

'--> Shell loads a Module (Module A)

'----> Module A (based on business logic) loads View 1 *or* View 2

Now, the shell is in the executable that loads all my modules from the app.config.  The modules are developed by middle-tier developers.  The views are developed by the front-end developers and compiled to a different DLL.  The only 'glue' is that the modules have the ViewModel in them.  At runtime, based on the logic, the module will load a view (from an external DLL) and register it with the region setting the view's DataContext to the ViewModel in the module.

Note: The Shell has no reference to either the Module or the View.  Likewise, the Module has no reference to the View.

The module inherits from an interface and is loaded at runtime.

Again, how do I get the module to load the external view at runtime?

Thanks.

Comment: What about using a DI container to dynamically scan and register the views if there is one per interface in the external dll?

Comment: Well, that's what I'd like, but I'm not exactly sure how to do it.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Many IoC containers support this feature. For an example of scanning and registering Types dynamically using Structuremap see http://docs.structuremap.net/ScanningAssemblies.htm.

Comment: In the example, instead of using the calling assembly, you can specify another assembly or all assemblies in a folder

Comment: Did this help, I can add as answer

Comment: i know how to load an external assembly.  I just don't know how to use IoC to "pull out" the view (usercontrol) to place it in container.